# how to set UIView Background color with glass effect similar to UIAlertView

Tags: iphone

i need to place one textfield with 3 buttons in an alertview. According to UIGuidelines it is not possible,so Instead of AlertView I place UIView similar to Alertview.

And i animate it like Alert view using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690775/creating-a-pop-animation-similar-to-the-presentation-of-uialertview).

If works fine.

it displays with white Color Background,But i need to design same as AlertView Background color and style like round edged.

How can i done this.

can anyone pls help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIAlertView background is simply an image. You are better off creating a custom png image and using it as your background.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with CoreGraphics / Quartz functions, but it is quite complicate to simulate the same effect
Another approach would be to create a UIImageView with a streched uiimage you mock in Photoshop or so.

;)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** You can set a custom view directly into UIAlertView like this:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    [_addPersonAlert setValue:auxContainerView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
}else{
    [_addPersonAlert addSubview:auxContainerView];
}
```

There are a lot of open source, subclasses of UIAlertView that might accomplish what you want to do. I'll leave a couple as an example but you can certainly google out some other options as well.

https://github.com/rtecson/RTAlertView

https://github.com/lmcd/LMAlertView

In my case I used once, LMAlertView which let's you access it's "contentView" property, to set any UIView that you want as part of the alert. Have in mind that you can add a hierarchy of views into a single UIView and set this container view as the contentView of the alert.