# iphone - Focus effect (just like UIAlertView)

Tags: iphone, focus

I know title of my question is so bad, but I don't know how to describe it.

When an UIAlertView pops up, anything else on the screen (except the UIAlertView) becomes a bit darker but can be seen. I call this as Focus effect, because you will know clearly and directly that now the UIAlertView is the focus.

So how can I implement such a focus effect?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a translucent view below the view you want to "focus" on.
Simple example:

```
UIView *shieldView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myView.bounds] autorelease];
shieldView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.7];
[myView.superview insertSubview:shieldView belowSubview:myView];
```

`UIAlertView` actually uses an image with a radial gradient instead of a simple color, in order to highlight the center of the view.

Comment: What do you mean by "not good"? As I said, the example is simplified. In a real-world app, you would most likely add fade-in/out animations and use a gradient image instead of a simple color...

Comment: I think I should first animate fade-in/out for the shieldView, and then pop up my focused view?

Comment: If I have time I will try to make some animation to open a view, and closing a view.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is a bit old but I thought it might help someone.

Use this code to generate the radial gradient background:

```
- (UIImage *)radialGradientImage:(CGSize)size start:(float)start end:(float)end centre:(CGPoint)centre radius:(float)radius{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 1);

size_t count = 2;
CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0, 1.0};
CGFloat components[8] = {start, start, start, 1.0, end, end, end, 1.0};

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGGradientRef grad = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorSpace, components, locations, count);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawRadialGradient (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), grad, centre, 0, centre, radius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

CGGradientRelease(grad);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;}
```

Define gradient in the .h file like so:

```
UIImageView *gradient;
```

Call your gradient like so:

```
- (void)addGradient{
CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
CGPoint centre = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);

float startColor = 1.0f; 
float endColor = 0.0f;
float radius = MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width/4, self.view.bounds.size.height/4); 

gradient = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self radialGradientImage:size 
                                                                  start:startColor 
                                                                    end:endColor 
                                                                 centre:centre 
                                                                 radius:radius]];

[gradient setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[gradient setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[gradient setAlpha:0.6f];
[self.view addSubview:gradient];}
```

Comment: I have found that if you do float radius = MIN(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height); 
it looks a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

`UIAlertView` works like this. It fades in an alpha mask image to dim out the background. Once that animation is finished it starts the "bounce in" animation of the dialog.

So to reproduce it you need first to generate an alpha mask with a "bright spot" where your dialog will end up and fade that in. Then use a (few) frame animation(s) to get the bounce effect.

More info here: [Creating a Pop animation similar to the presentation of UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2690775/742314)

Comment: I guess the UIAlertView is bounced out at the same time the mask image begins the dimming animation, just the animation's duration is quite shot 0.3 sec??

Comment: I've never really timed the Apple stuff. If you google it you will find people who have. I just wanted to give you the basic idea of what you need to reproduce it. Either create an image with a radial blur, distorted by a transform right on the simulator and save it off or use gimp or photoshop. The timing is between you and CoreAnimation ;-) BTW this is not just speculation, I have written code to do this but it was for clients so can't share!

Answer (score 0):

To make it better than "not good" you could ...

1. create a UIView in a nib (easiest if the part of your code where you need the effect is already utilising a nib) and then add a translucent graphic (with a 'focus' effect) to that view.
2. connect the UIView in the nib to an IBOutlet
3. fade in the graphic using an animation into view hierarchy (omz example shows this)