# Popup notification box

Tags: ios, animation, popup

Im trying to create a popup style notification, which is shown at the top of the screen (using a basic animation). The notification is going to be a simple form with a submit button.

Im trying to figure out how to go about this, and what are the best options i have. I've found this popup library: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cqmfloatingcontroller

What are the best options for 1. creating the popup and 2. animating to popup

[image: Mockup of what I need]

Answer (score 1):

If this is something that you will be reusing a lot, it might be worth subclassing UIAlertView, as you can then automatically use all "popup" methods provided by it,and by customizing it's view you can get the appearance you want.

Comment: is there a way to make the alert view, come in from the top (ie. animation) and disappear to the top of the screen when its closed

Comment: also can i position the alertview at anywhere i want

Comment: You can position the AlertView anywhere you want by setting its frame property 
MyAlertViewSubclass *alert = [[MyAlertViewSubclass alloc] init];
alert.frame = CGRectMake(originX, originY, alertWidth, alertHeight)

Comment: and for the animation, you can use some methods similiar to the described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690775/creating-a-pop-animation-similar-to-the-presentation-of-uialertview)

Comment: is there a way i can put the `Go` button next to the text field as shown in my screenshot?

Comment: Of course! Since UIAlertView inherit from UIView, you can add subviews (ie, UIButtons, UITextFields, etc) to it as much as you want.. you just need to set the frame of each of the subviews...
You can do this both with Nibs or Programatically...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.